# select multiple rows different value from same table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is my table "**OPTIONS**"

[image]

Here i need to get site_logo,facebook and twitter values only from single mysql query.

Thank you

Comment: `select * from options`

Comment: you should have better taken efforts learn **very** basics of SQL before posting any question, this question only shows lack of efforts to just know what you want to achieve

Answer (score 1):

As simple as it is..

`SELECT id,option_key,option_value FROM options`

or

`SELECT * FROM options`

You can do like this Using **PDO**

```
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:dbname=pages;host=localhost", "username", "password");
    $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT id,option_key,option_value FROM options');
    $sth->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME ;
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM options` then, in the PHP:

```
while ($row=MySQLi_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo "<option value=\"".htmlspecialchars($row['option_value'])."\">".
    htmlspecialchars($row['option_key'])."</option>";
}
```

Comment: and don't forget to use `htmlspecialchars` for this approach