# MySQL: Get multiple row's different values to one single column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is my table structure

My table name siteInfo

```
id    | key         | value

1     | facebook    | facebook.com

2     | twitter     | twitter.com

3     | googleplus  | google.com

4     | linkedin    | linkedin.com
```

here how i can get facebook and googleplus values from single sql column

Comment: You've posted the same question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23149606/select-multiple-rows-different-value-from-same-table
And I answered in a way that would work. Why have you asked the question again?

Comment: retrieve two rows and concate it

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for,

```
select group_concat(`value` separator ', ') url
from siteinfo
where `key` in ('facebook','googleplus');
```

here is, [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9b06c4/2)